François Truffaut - Los 4 Golpes
Yesterday I went to see a screening of Truffaut's La sirène du Mississipi (aka Mississippi Mermaid). It's prelude was a short film called Los 4 Golpes and it was also directed by Truffaut, but I can't seem to find any info whatsoever except on the site of the filmfestival where I saw it.

It's a short movie about 4 minutes long where we see Truffaut getting mad about something in a newspaper. He follows several people while massacring their newspapers and at the end Truffaut strangles a woman with her scarf. However, it turns out that this is a film in film and Truffaut explains something to a cameraman.

Does anybody have any information about this short? There was no audio btw and the title page was in Spanish. It translates to something like The 4 Blows (not to be confused with Truffaut's The 400 Blows). The filmfestival says the country of origin is Argentina.

I've a lot, I'm from Argentina. What are you looking for?

Picking nits here, but this really isn't an identify-this-movie request, as you already know the name of the film. What are you really looking for? Any information at all, is a pretty broad request. Please note, however, I neither down-voted nor voted-to-close.

That site claims that the short was never seen before, so that might explain the lack of information. Maybe it's a bit he did for a TV show or a documentary; the strangling scene sounds like a Frenzy tribute (Truffaut greatly admired Hitchcock).

@CGCampbell I also had my doubts about the tag but seeing as I don't know if Truffaut directed in Argentina (or some other Spanish speaking country), I had my doubts whether Los 4 Golpes was the real title or a translated one

@Walt I know but just because it wasn't shown before it doesn't mean that there is no information of it to be found. Now that you say it, it did look like a tribute to Frenzy. It just wasn't an excerpt from something else, it had an opening page and credits and a 'fin'

Finally found some extra info:

In need to watch all of Alfred Hitchcock’s films in order to prepare
  for his famous interview, François Truffaut travelled regularly to the
  Cinémathèque Royale. Like many other French filmmakers, he knew that a
  weekly train ride to Brussels, where Jacques Ledoux would be happy to
  screen the films (in original version, on top!), would be much easier
  and less stressful than trying to do the same in Paris. Later, as
  thank you gift he gave the Cinémathèque a copy of a small film nobody
  had heard about: on the can, just a title, Los 4 golpes. We know very
  little about the film that appears to have been made by Truffaut and a
  group of friends in Mar del Plata on the occasion of the film
  festival. The year must have been 1962, when the festival awarded
  Truffaut as best director for Jules et Jim. Unknown to all
  filmographies and biographies, it is just a 3-minute divertissement, a
  thriller (Truffaut plays ‘the assassin’) complete with (very) complete
  cast and credits. Shot on 16mm, in a style between amateur and
  film-noir, in black and white and silent (although the complete cast
  and credits mention “music by J.S. Bach” – a gag?, perhaps to be
  screend with discs?), Los 4 golpes has all the freshness of an
  afternoon amusement: a camera, a group of friends, and Truffaut
  playing assassin and director!

Source
Same info but in Italian

I saw the film at the Truffaut exhibition in Paris. Yes, it was never seen before!
I added the film here :
https://rateyourmusic.com/film/los_4_golpes/
It was made before "Frenzy" in 1962.
It was made for/at an argentina film festival at Mar de Plata. It was shoot at the the hotel Hermitage. I think it was shoot on 16mm, in black & white. 
Credits: 
El Asasino: Francois Truffaut
La Victima: Gloria Algorta
Complice n°1: Christiane Rochefort
Complice n°2: Marie Laforêt
"Argumento de Jorge De' ANgeli sobre una idea de Gloria Alorta"
Muscia: JS Bach

Alright, didn't know that the short has aired in Paris. I couldn't recall the credits but your information looks correct. Hopefully this will help other people in a search for more info
